# setting dynamic row size of UICollectionViewController as per height of its item

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using `UICollectionViewController` for displaying some item like images. I want to set `UICollectionViewController` row height as per highest height of my item in that row. similarly every row should adjust its size according to the item which has highest height in that row.

please help me...

Comment: Create a custom collection view controller layout.

Comment: i am new to objective-c, can you tell me how to create custom collection view controller layout.